# Indexing Dataframe similar to numpy ndarray with 2d index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

**Motivation:**

I have 3-dimensional velocity data stored in an Nx3 DataFrame. I need to detect events in the data and extract fixed length epochs for further analysis. I would like to store the detected epochs as an additional index/column in the DataFrame and use it to get a compact 2d representation of the epoch data across all 3 dimensions. I feel like this should be possible through some combination of functions like `df.stack`, `df.unstack`, `df.pivot` etc but I can't work out how to do it.

---

With numpy arrays I can use a 2d index into an array to do something like this

```
>>> arr = np.arange(30).reshape((10, 3))

>>> arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29]])

>>> idx = np.array([[2, 5, 8],
                    [3, 6, 9]])

>>> np.concatenate(arr[idx].T).T
array([[ 6, 15, 24,  7, 16, 25,  8, 17, 26],
       [ 9, 18, 27, 10, 19, 28, 11, 20, 29]])
```

Is there a nice way to do something similar in pandas to go from a dataframe like this

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
>>> df.index = [NaN, NaN, 0, 0, NaN, 1, 1, NaN, 2, 2]
>>> df
      X   Y   Z 
NaN   0   1   2
NaN   3   4   5
0     6   7   8
0     9  10  11
NaN  12  13  14
1    15  16  17
1    18  19  20
NaN  21  22  23
2    24  25  26
2    27  28  29
```

To something like this?

```
   X           Y           Z
   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
0  6  15  24   7  16  25   8  17  26
1  9  18  27  10  19  28  11  20  29
```

Of course, I could do all of the work with numpy and create a new DataFrame from the result, but it would be nice to have all of the index/column labels automatically sort themselves out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following Pandas approach:

```
In [270]: x = df.loc[df.index.notnull()]

In [271]: x
Out[271]:
      X   Y   Z
0.0   6   7   8
0.0   9  10  11
1.0  15  16  17
1.0  18  19  20
2.0  24  25  26
2.0  27  28  29

In [278]: (x.set_index(np.arange(len(x)) // 2)
            .set_index(np.arange(len(x)) % 2, append=True)
            .unstack(0))
Out[278]:
   X           Y           Z
   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
0  6  15  24   7  16  25   8  17  26
1  9  18  27  10  19  28  11  20  29
```

or using multi-index:

```
In [305]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(([0,1,2],[0,1]))

In [306]: x.set_index(idx).unstack(0)
Out[306]:
   X           Y           Z
   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
0  6  15  24   7  16  25   8  17  26
1  9  18  27  10  19  28  11  20  29
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets the job done. I think I can simplify things by adding a MultiIndex to the original array

Comment: @user3419537, sure, you can use MultiIndex (see updated answer), but you will need to think how to build it up dynamically...

Comment: I already have all the information I need from the epoch detection. With a MultiIndex in place I can write `df[~df.index.duplicated(keep=False)].unstack(0)`